# Math.floor returns NaN

Tags: javascript

I am using javascript to remove .0 from the value in  innerHtml.
It is working fine in localhost but when i uploaded at server it is returning 'NaN'. When i reload the page it shows value for a second and then it shows NaN. Following is javascript function

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var aliasstart = document.getElementById('aliasstart').innerText;
        document.getElementById('aliasstart').innerText =parseInt( Math.floor(aliasstart));
    });
</script>
```

AliasStart is of type decimal in MVC model class
I have given the part of the code.
Please help

Comment: put `parseFloat(aliasstart)` inside `Math.floor` because aliasstart is a string not a number, that's why it is giving NaN.

Comment: Thank you so much shubham that worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it the other way 'round `Math.floor(parseFloat(aliasstart));`